# How to remove the day from the date and leave only the month and year from a column in a large dataset in r markdown?

Tags: r

I have a large dataset and one of the columns includes dates formatted DD/MM/YYYY and I would like to just have MM/YYYY. Is there a way to apply this to the entire column in the dataset `dat$date`?

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to `Date` class first with `as.Date` and then use `format`

```
dat$date <- format(as.Date(dat$date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%m/%Y")
```

Or another option is regex to match the digits (`\\d+`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by `/` and replace with blank (`''`)

```
dat$date <- sub("^\\d+\\/", "", dat$date)
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(date = c('05/10/2015', '15/05/2010'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: The second option worked better but it gave me the day instead of the month is there a way to get the month instead?

Comment: @MCM you said the format is DD/MM/YYYY so it is removing the DD/